# Error in UIAuitomator Code

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

My code is as follows,

```
package com.example.automatorapp.test;

import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;

public class Try2 extends UiAutomatorTestCase 
{

public void demo() throws UiObjectNotFoundException
{


    getUiDevice().pressHome();
}



 }
```

and the error is...

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception during suite construction
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests.testSuiteConstructionFailed(TestSuiteBuilder.java:238)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.instantiateTest(TestMethod.java:93)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.createTest(TestMethod.java:73)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTest(TestSuiteBuilder.java:262)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.build(TestSuiteBuilder.java:184)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:379)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4382)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase.<init>(UiAutomatorTestCase.java:5)
at com.example.automatorapp.test.Pun.<init>(Pun.java:10)
... 18 more
```

My MainActivity has no problem.It works fine.but this test case has gives some errors.And can u plz tell me how can i add javadocs of uiautomator.jar.As i am unable to find apk of javadoc of uiautomator?

Comment: You need to post all the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

Testcases need to have the standard junit 3 style method signature of `public void test...() { ... }`

Your code has a method of `demo()` Once you add the prefix test as follows, `testdemo()` then the test is found and executed.

For completeness, here is the difference between the 2 when the tests are run. Firstly, what's essentially your code with the method `public void demo()`

```
UIAutomatorExample$ adb shell uiautomator runtest UIAutomatorExample.jar -c com.example.automatoapp.test.Try2
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=
Time: 0.0

OK (0 tests)
```

And once the method has been named correctly to `public void testdemo()`

```
UIAutomatorExample$ adb shell uiautomator runtest UIAutomatorExample.jar -c com.example.automatoapp.test.Try2
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=com.example.automatoapp.test.Try2
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
com.example.automatoapp.test.Try2:
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testdemo
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=com.example.automatoapp.test.Try2
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testdemo
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
Time: 1.53

OK (1 test)
```

And here's the corrected version of the example code:

```
package com.example.automatoapp.test;

import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;

public class Try2 extends UiAutomatorTestCase 
{
    public void testdemo() throws UiObjectNotFoundException
    {
        getUiDevice().pressHome();
    }
}
```